# Prolog: How to remove every second element of a list

Tags: list, prolog

I need to write a program in Prolog that should remove every second element of a list. Should work this: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] -> [1,3,5,7]

so far I have this, but it just returns "false".

```
r([], []). 
r([H|[T1|T]], R) :- del(T1,[H[T1|T]], R), r(R).

del(X,[X|L],L).
del(X,[Y|L],[Y|L1]):- del(X,L,L1).
```

Comment: You seem to have a typo in the second clause for **r/2** where it calls **del/3**, in that the second argument is not a proper term. Also you then call a one-argument predicate **r**, where presumably you meant to call the two-argument **r/2**.  By the way, a more concise way to write `[H|[T1|T]]` is `[H,T1|T]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is pretty much Landei's answer in specific Prolog syntax:

```
r([], []).
r([X], [X]).
r([X,_|Xs], [X|Ys]) :- r(Xs, Ys).
```

The second predicate is not required.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative solution using [foldl/4](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foldl/4):

```
fold_step(Item, true:[Item|Tail], false:Tail).
fold_step(_Item, false:Tail, true:Tail).

odd(List, Odd) :-
    foldl(fold_step, List, true:Odd, _:[]).
```

Usage:

```
?- odd([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], Odd).
Odd = [1, 3, 5, 7]
```

The idea is to go through the list, while keeping "odd/even" flag and flipping its value (false -> true, true -> false) on each element. We also gradually construct the list, by appending those elements which have "odd/even" flag equal to true, and skipping others.

Comment: Good! However, your explanation is somewhat incomplete: `odd/2` can work in different instantiation modes and give reasonable answers, too! ;) Consider the solutions to the query `?- odd(Xs,[a,b,c]).`

Answer (score 3):

[This fine answer by @code_x386](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46844024/4609915) utilizes [difference-lists](/questions/tagged/difference-lists) and `foldl/4`.

Let's use only one `fold_step/3` clause *and* make the relation more general, like so:

```
fold_step(X, [X|Xs]+Ys, Ys+Xs).

list_odds_evens(List, Odds, Evens) :-
   foldl(fold_step, List, Odds+Evens, []+[]).
```

Sample queries:

```
?– list_odds_evens([a,b,c,d,e,f], Odds, Evens).
Evens = [b,d,f], Odds = [a,c,e]
?– list_odds_evens([a,b,c,d,e,f,g], Odds, Evens).
Evens = [b,d,f], Odds = [a,c,e,g]
```

---

#### Edit

Why not use *one clause less* and do away with predicate `fold_step/3`?
[lambda](/questions/tagged/lambda) to the rescue!

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

list_odds_evens(List, Odds, Evens) :-
   foldl(\X^([X|Xs]+Ys)^(Ys+Xs)^true, List, Odds+Evens, []+[]).
```

Comment: @tas. Above code is just like https://stackoverflow.com/a/8091652/4609915  `foldl/4` style;)

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use DCGs, they are usually a worthwhile consideration when describing lists:

```
list_oddindices(L,O) :-
   phrase(oddindices(L),O).  % the list O is described by oddindices//1

oddindices([]) -->           % if L is empty
   [].                       % O is empty as well
oddindices([X]) -->          % if L has just one element
   [X].                      % it's in O
oddindices([O,_E|OEs]) -->   % if L's head consists of at least two elements
   [O],                      % the first is in O
   oddindices(OEs).          % the same holds for the tail
```

This is certainly less elegant than the solutions using foldl/4 but the code is very easily readable, yet it solves the task described by the OP and works both ways as well:

```
?- list_oddindices([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],O).
O = [1, 3, 5, 7] ;
false.

?- list_oddindices(L,[1,3,5,7]).
L = [1, _G4412, 3, _G4418, 5, _G4424, 7] ;
L = [1, _G4412, 3, _G4418, 5, _G4424, 7, _G4430] ;
false.
```

Comment: Some more determinism?

Answer (score 0):

I have no Prolog here to try it out, and I got a little bit rusty, but it should be along the lines of

```
r([]) :- [].
r([X]) :- [X].
r([X,Y|Z]) :- R=r(Z),[X|R].
```

**[Edit]**

Of course pad is right. My solution would work in functional languages like Haskell or Erlang:

```
--Haskell
r [] = []
r [x] = [x]
r (x:_:xs) = x : (r xs)
```

In Prolog you have to "pull" the right sides into the argument list in order to trigger unification.

Comment: The Haskell code is ok, but **your Prolog code is broken**. The question is tagged [tag:prolog]—not [tag:haskell]. Bad!

Answer (score 0):

I just needed a function like this and took a more "mathematical" approach:

```
odds(Xs, Ys) :- findall(X, (nth1(I,Xs,X), I mod 2 =:= 1), Ys).
```

It doesn't work both ways like some of the other fine answers here, but it's short and sweet.