# Move every second element to the back of a list, recursively

Tags: recursion, prolog, difference-lists

I'm looking for a way to shuffle a list of numbers in a specific way.

`shuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])` should return `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 2, 6, 10, 4, 12, 8]`

The recursion would be something like this:

```
[1,3,5,7,9,11] with remainder [2,4,6,8,10,12]
[2,6,10] with remainder [4,8,12]
[4,12] with remainder [8]
```

and then you append the result lists and return the wanted answer.

My current code looks like this. How can I adapt it so that it produces the type of recursion I explained above? the mode is `shuffle(+,?)`.

```
shuffle([], _).
shuffle(List, Shuffled) :- r(List, Shuffled).
r([], []).
r([X], [X]):- !.
r([X,A|Xs], [X|Ys]) :- r(Xs, Ys).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a predicate that gets half the work done: reorders the list so that every second element is picked out and appended to the back, keeping the order:

```
untangle([], []).
untangle([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :-
    untangle_1([X|Xs], [X|Ys], Bs, Bs).

% The rest of the Untangled is the list at the back;
% the list at the back is now empty
untangle_1([], Back, Back, []).
% Keep elements in odd positions at the front
untangle_1([X|Xs], [X|Untangled], Back, Bs) :-
    untangle_2(Xs, Untangled, Back, Bs).

% Same as above
untangle_2([], Back, Back, []).
% Move elements in even positions to the back
untangle_2([X|Xs], Untangled, Back, [X|Bs]) :-
    untangle_1(Xs, Untangled, Back, Bs).
```

This is very similar to the `interwine/3` defined [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321457/zip-function-in-prolog/8328638#8328638). Instead of using two lists for the "unzipped" elements, it puts them at the front and back of the same list.

Now what you need is shuffle the elements that would otherwise be appended to the back:

```
shuffle([], []).
shuffle([X|Xs], Shuffled) :-
    untangle_1([X|Xs], Shuffled, Back, Bs),
    shuffle(Bs, Back).
```

Did I understand that correctly?

```
?- shuffle([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z], S), write(S).
[a,c,e,g,i,k,m,o,q,s,u,w,y,b,f,j,n,r,v,z,d,l,t,h,x,p]
S = [a, c, e, g, i, k, m, o, q|...].
```

You will also notice that this `shuffle/2` works in modes `shuffle(+List, -Shuffled)`, `shuffle(-List, +Shuffled)`, and `shuffle(?List, ?Shuffled)`. To what I can see, it is identical in semantics (and almost identical in implementation) to the solution of false.

Comment: Yep you nailed it! That is correct. Gonna do some more testing but it looks to be working the way I want it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version using DCGs:

```
eo([], Ys,Ys) -->
   [].
eo([X|Xs], [X|Ys0],Ys) -->
   eo2(Xs, Ys0,Ys).

eo2([], Ys,Ys) -->
   [].
eo2([X|Xs], Ys0,Ys) -->
   [X],
   eo(Xs, Ys0,Ys).

list_shuffled(Xs, Ys0) :-
    phrase(eo(Xs, Ys0,Ys),Ys).
```

And here is the most general query showing *all* possible uses:

```
?- list_shuffled(Xs,Ys), numbervars(Xs+Ys,0,_).
   Xs = Ys, Ys = []
;  Xs = Ys, Ys = [A]
;  Xs = Ys, Ys = [A, B]
;  Xs = [A, B, C], Ys = [A, C, B]
;  Xs = [A, B, C, D], Ys = [A, C, B, D]
;  Xs = [A, B, C, D, E], Ys = [A, C, E, B, D]
;  Xs = [A, B, C, D, E, F], Ys = [A, C, E, B, D, F]
;  Xs = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G], Ys = [A, C, E, G, B, D, F]
;  ... .
```

Comment: Indeed, if difference lists are involved, a DCG is almost invariably clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another, somewhat transparent solution using `append`:

```
shuffle([], []).
shuffle([X|T], Shuffled) :-
    unzip([X|T], Odd, Even),
    shuffle(Even, EvenShuffled),
    append(Odd, EvenShuffled, Shuffled).

% Split a list into odd and even elements
unzip([], [], []).
unzip([X], [X], []).
unzip([X,Y|T], [X|Tx], [Y|Ty]) :-
    unzip(T, Tx, Ty).
```

For the record, I do prefer Boris' and false's solutions to this one (+1 to both) as both are more efficient. :)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321457/zip-function-in-prolog/8328638#8328638

Comment: @false, that's excellent. My `unzip` is really what salvo defined as a `shuffle`, and his solution is more elegant than mine.

Comment: Steal it! Or even better: Use it and refer to it!